# Ubuntu Program bar Icons different

Tags: titlebar

My Problem is that the maximize, close and minimize buttons aren't the default ones and it's really irritating me.

This happend after installing the kde plasma desktop and then removing it.
If anyone knows how to fix this please comment below.

edit 1:
I tried reinstalling the ubuntu desktop adn that didn't fix the issue.

[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0prS.png)

[what I have now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Wet0.png)

Answer (score 0):

Go into settings -> appearance. There your should be able to change to icons you're using. There is another tab for window titlebars. Check that one out too.
Also take a look at Gnome-Tweak-Tool. It should make it easy to customise your theme.

Comment: Even when changing icons it won't work